# [Django]How to resolve the following error(in views.py)?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

On running the code given in chapter nine of howtotangowith django site,i get the following error in views.py:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/register/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rango')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"        in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,      *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Blue\code\tango_with_django_project\rango\views.py" in     register
  78.         user_form=UserForm(data=request.POST)

Exception Type: TypeError at /rango/register/
Exception Value: this constructor takes no arguments
```

code of UserForm:

```
class UserForm:
password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=('username','email','password')
```

!!!!
Have no idea what to todo to resolve this error please help

Comment: Show the code of the `UserForm`, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inherit `UserForm` from the `ModelForm`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```